# window.location.href thymeleaf multiple variables

Tags: html, thymeleaf

How I can pass multiple variables to
`th:onclick="'window.location.href = \'' + @{/reutilizar_macrociclo/{id}(id=${macrociclo.planificacion.id})} + '\''"` ?

I want id and id_training, but I don´t know how to add id_training.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add several parameters, separating them with commas like:

`<a th:href="@{/order/details(id=3,action='show_all')}">`

For more details check [Standard URL Syntax - Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html)